# Is calling a method in Java the same as sending a message to an object in Objective-C?

Tags: java, objective-c, binding, methods, message

The Java's syntax for calling a method is the following:

```
object.methodName(...)
```

In Objective-C, the syntax for sending a message to an object is the following:

```
[object methodName:...]
```

Better, suppose you have an interface in Java (say Aj) and an object which implements this interface (say Bj).
Suppose also to have a protocol in Objective-C (say Ac) and a class which implements that protocol (say Bc).

**Java:**

```
Aj object = new Bj();
Aj.method();
```

**Objective-C:**

```
Ac* object = [[Bc alloc] init];
[Ac method];
```

Obviously it is different. But what I think is: in both cases the binding of the method to the right object is done dynamically, then I think that also Java uses messages and chooses the right method at runtime. Is it correct?

Can I affirm that also Java uses the "messages' mechanism" for calling object's methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this article, it looks like the Java VM has a similar "message" mechanism to Obj-C: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1571983

Just breezed through it though, could be wrong.

Comment: Yes, I think I cannot say those are the same thing, but I understand that the base mechanism is similar (at least when the Java binding is done dynamically).

Answer (score 1):

One important difference is that Objective-C allows you to pass messages to `nil`. If you try to call a method on `null` in Java, it won't compile.